# Find Taylor Polynomial

Tags: calculus

> Find the Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)=\sin(e^{x+2})$ around $x_0=-2$ and of order $2$.

We can write $f(x)=\sin(t)$, where $t=e^{x+2}$, so we have:

$f(-2)=\sin(e^{x+2})=\sin(e^{0})=\sin(1)$

$f^{(1)}(-2)=\cos(t)=\cos(e^{x+2})=\cos(1)$

$f^{(2)}(-2)=-\sin(t)=-\sin(e^{x+2})=-\sin(1)$

so the Taylor Polynomial $$P_n(x,-2)=\sin(1)+\frac{\cos(1)}{1!}\cdot(x+2)-\frac{\sin(1)}{2!}\cdot(x+2)^2$$

fixed attempt after feedback:

$f(-2)=\sin(e^{x+2})=\sin(e^{0})=\sin(1)$
$f^{(1)}(-2)=t'\cos(t)=e^{x+2}\cdot\cos(e^{x+2})=\cos(1)$
$f^{(2)}(-2)=e^{x+2}\cdot\cos(e^{x+2})-e^{x+2}\cdot\sin(e^{x+2})=\cos(1)-\sin(1)$

so the Taylor Polynomial $$P_n(x,-2)=\sin(1)+\frac{\cos(1)}{1!}\cdot(x+2)+\frac{\cos(1)-\sin(1)}{2!}\cdot(x+2)^2$$

is the a mistake?

Comment: Firstly, the question should be why you think there is a mistake. Secondly, you do have a mistake, which is that you're differentiating with respect to the mysterious variable $t$ instead of with respect to $x$, and therefore casting the chain rule out of the window.

Comment: @mixedmath derived it again, now it is seems ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)=\sin(e^{x+2})$ is
$$
f'(x)=e^{x+2}\cos(e^{x+2})
$$
(chain rule) and the second derivative is
$$
f''(x)=e^{x+2}\cos(e^{x+2})-e^{x+2}\cdot e^{x+2}\sin(e^{x+2})
$$
(product rule and chain rule).

Thus
\begin{align}
f'(-2)&=\cos1\\
f''(-2)&=\cos1-\sin1
\end{align}

You get the right result but doing the wrong computations.